# jQuery-showLoading plugin , offset() is null

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, offset

i'm just copying some code from a web page (it should be easy) but there are some issues now and i don't know if they are connected to the css. However the showloading plugin of jQuery doesn't work and it stops the whole script from working. i get this error: TypeError: jQuery(...).offset(...) is null

It's taking the element which i applied showloading to and it cannot get the offset of it.Code:

```
var dialog = $("#response");
    dialog.fadeIn(500);
    dialog.showLoading(500);
```

I tried setting the styles for the element but the error is still showing up:

```
<div id="#response" style="postition: absolute; top: 150px; left: 50px;">
    <div id="Canvas"></div>
    <div id="#adx-img"></div>
    <div id="#adx-body"></div>
    <div id="#adx-ads"></div>
    <div id="#adx-cat"></div>
    <div id ="adx-flg"></div>
</div>
```

When i try ti inspect "jQuery(this)" from firebug it reports it as the whole window, not only the element i passed as an argument to the function showLoading. So i'm a bit confused. I don't think i should change something in jQuery.showLoading plugin, maybe the code in my page is not clear. Anyone has any hint? Agnese

Answer (score 0):

I see you start your id names with '#'. Maybe you mistook it for convention, but I can't get it working for myself like this.
The '#' is used for CSS-selectors (like jQuery uses) and is prepended to an id name to select the element with that id.

For you this would change the following:

```
<div id="response" style="postition: absolute; top: 150px; left: 50px;">
  <div id="Canvas"></div>
  <div id="adx-img"></div>
  <div id="adx-body"></div>
  <div id="adx-ads"></div>
  <div id="adx-cat"></div>
  <div id="adx-flg"></div>
</div>
```

I think this should solve your problem, especially because FireBug reports 'this' as the whole window.

Comment: Try adding 'dialog.hide();' before your fadeIn. It can't fade in without being hidden. Something might have gone wrong there.